# AngularJS: How to validate date format (DD/MM/YYYY) when manual enter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, date

I am use angular js 1.4 version. I am checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146655/angularjs-how-to-validate-date-in-us-format) and checked with regular expression too, but not help me. When I try  '2013-11-33' (in above link), its validate true, which is wrong.

[image]

This is my html

```
.. <div class="form-item">
    <!--<input required ng-model="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth* dd/mm/yyyy" class="textbox-n dob" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="dobTxt" name="dobTxt" min="1910-01-01" max="2013-12-31">-->
    <input required ng-model="user.dob" placeholder="Date of Birth* dd/mm/yyyy" class="dob" type="text" id="dobTxt" name="dobTxt">    
</div> 
.....
<!--Validation Summary-->
                <div class="alert alert-danger validationSum" role="alert" style="margin-bottom: -20px;"
                     ng-show="submitted &&
                     (registerForm.genderSelect.$error.required
                     || registerForm.firstNameTxt.$error.required || registerForm.lastNameTxt.$error.required
                     || registerForm.dobTxt.$error.required || registerForm.dobTxt.$error.date
                     || registerForm.mobileTxt.$error.required
                     || registerForm.emailTxt.$error.required || registerForm.emailTxt.$error.email || (user.email != confirmEmail) || emailExist
                     || registerForm.pharmacySelect.$error.required)">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-show="registerForm.genderSelect.$error.required">
                            Gender is required.
                        </li>
                        <li ng-show="registerForm.firstNameTxt.$error.required">
                            First name is required.
                        </li>
                        <li ng-show="registerForm.lastNameTxt.$error.required">
                            Last name is required.
                        </li>
                        <li ng-show="registerForm.dobTxt.$error.required">
                            Date of birth is required.
                        </li>
                        <li ng-show="registerForm.dobTxt.$error.date">
                            Not a valid date!
                        </li>
                        <li ng-show="registerForm.mobileTxt.$error.required">
                            Contact number is required.
                        </li>
                        <li ng-show="registerForm.emailTxt.$error.required">
                            Email is required.
                        </li>
                        <li ng-show="registerForm.emailTxt.$error.email">
                            Invalid email.
                        </li>
                        <li ng-show="isEmailMatched = (user.email != confirmEmail)">
                            Emails have to match!
                        </li>
                        <li ng-show="registerForm.pharmacySelect.$error.required">
                            Preferred pharmacy is required.
                        </li>
                        <li ng-show="emailExist">
                            This email has already been used to complete a questionnaire. Please contact your practitioner for your assessment.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Issue is when I entered wrong date , it is not fired. I tried some other links and plunker changes, but not resolve the issue.

Comment: You could try changing your input to `type="date"`.  That would also provide a selector.

Comment: I tried, but not give result

Comment: @senschen—not all browsers support input type date.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you aren't validating `user.dob` anywhere. You only check to see if `dobTxt` has input in the form of a date, but not whether or not that is a valid date.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177975/how-to-validate-date-with-format-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript) and [here](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/javascript-date-validation.php) are some examples of how to validate a date.

Comment: That is done in ' || registerForm.dobTxt.$error.required || registerForm.dobTxt.$error.date' here, and your link is for javascript, I want through angular.js

Comment: Angular.js is a javascript framework.  Your angular controller is written in javascript, so the links I provided are valid and useful here.  `registerForm.dobTxt.$error.required` checks to see that there is something in `dobTxt`, and `registerForm.dobTxt.$error.date` checks to see that it is in a valid *date format*, but does not check to see that that date is *valid*.  You have to validate the date yourself.

Comment: I understand, but what I will do next, how to check format via function. If you have toughs with above link, please suggest i.e. with sample code.

Comment: There's sample code in the links.  That's why I provided them.